# How can one install Slax to a qemu img?

Tags: debian, boot, qemu

Per the title, **I want to install Slax** (version 9.11.0) **to a .img file for use with qemu, as a virtual machine.** I've tried a bunch of things over four hours, and I've been unable to do this.

My understanding is with most distributions, you use `qemu-img` to create a `.img` file, use `qemu-system` to boot a `.iso` file with a `.img` provided, and most operating systems will provide some sort of "Install to disk" option. After doing so, you can simply boot using `qemu-system` and the `.img`. Changes will be saved to the `.img`.

But Slax is different, and offers no "Install to disk" method. Nothing is stored on the `.img`. It's acts like a live, non-persistent disk.

Slax still has an installation method. It's easy to create an installer on a physical device (such as a USB), with instructions here: https://www.slax.org/starting.php But I cannot find how to apply this method to a `.img` file!

Some possibly useful information about what I tried:

I tried to reproduce those instructions by using `dd` and `mkfs` to create a `.img` file with an `msdos` filesystem, but running the `bootinst.sh` did not work. With a bit of inspection, I see the script failed around line `127`, because `extlinux.x64` tried to run and reported `cannot find device for path .`, `cannot open device (null)`, returning exit code `1`. I don't know enough about images and filesystems to diagnose this, but I guess it's because my `.img` is not a physical device (like a USB.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Slax on qemu you need to:

1. create a hard disk image
2. boot the image

To create a hard disk image:

```
qemu-img create slax.img 4G
```

To boot the image:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda slax.img -cdrom slax-64bit-9.11.0.iso -boot d -m 512
```

username is `root` , password is `toor`.

Installing Slax:

Open the terminal , install `parted` , unmount `/dev/sda`

```
apt install parted
umount /media/sda
```

Use `fdisk` , `parted` ... to create an `ext4` partition

[**NB**](https://www.slax.org/starting.php)

> It is required that your disk uses msdos partition scheme (use MBR, not GPT). Furthermore, it needs to be formatted, FAT32 or ext4 is recommended.

```
partprobe
mkdir /mnt/slax
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/slax
cp -R /media/sr0/slax/ /mnt/slax/
cd /mnt/slax/slax/boot
./bootinst.sh
cd
umount /mnt/slax
umount /media/sr0
poweroff
```

Then run:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda slax.img -boot d -m 1000
```

[Debian wiki: QEMU](https://wiki.debian.org/QEMU)

Comment: This doesn't install it to create a bootable `slax.img` though. (Such a thing would work in other distros, but not this one.)

Comment: @lynn answer update, including how to install slax.

Comment: @lynn have you tried my edit? I have installed slax on qemu, it work without problem. Could you confirm?

Comment: I'm sorry -- I haven't gotten the time to get around to trying this yet. Particularly the `fdisk` and `parted` part I would need to learn how to do.